# i am getting an error while launching AVD in emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Cannot launch `AVD` in emulator.

i did what you have mentioned..but still facing the error as:

> Hax is enabled
>
> Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
>
> Hax ram_size 0x60000000
>
> Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>
> Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
>
> Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
>
> Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
>
> Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
>
> Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
>
> Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
>
> Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
>
> Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
>
> Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
>
> Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
>
> console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
>
> adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server

i don't know what is this since am a beginner to android development...pls anyone help me to get rid off this?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your heap size. Go to the AVD configuration and change it to 384MB or more
[image]

**EDIT**

The error you've included indicates that the graphics driver on your desktop machine doesn't support the GL extensions that the emulator needs. Turn off Use host GPU in the AVD settings.

Also you may check google group [discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930#c27)

Comment: @Sam what is the error this time? Can you update your question?

Comment: yup..i have updated the question.thanx for the reply

Comment: @Sam which version of SDK Tools are you using? I saw that there is an opened issue on google's issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=198226&aid=1982260007000&name=emu+25.0.4+rc+5+(run+tab+from+Android+Studio+2.0+preview9).txt&token=ABZ6GAfKlfYDoE-h5tHKmz7JiA5WCvXiWg%3A1459189399486

Comment: i'm using sdk 23.1 revision..the issue you have mentioned is same as mine.....what can i do now??

Comment: Check my updated answer please. Also check link with google discussion

Comment: yup i saw that.....Disable OpenGLES emulation support by renaming <android-sdk-root>\tools\lib\libOpenglRender.dll to libOpenglRender.dll.disabled. Or,

* Reduce the amount of memory used by the emulator. Try 900MB, if that doesn't work, try 800MB, if that doesn't work, try 700MB, you get the idea.

Comment: i reduced the memory size of the emulator to 700MB..but  still same error...!!!!!...:(

Answer (score 1):

Just select software GLES from the Emulated performance in AVD settings if you are using latest android studio.